# PrintWriter not outputing to file

Tags: java, file, io, printwriter

Whenever the next segment of code is run, I get the new csv file created, but I don't get anything written to it:

```
PrintWriter fout     = null;

    try {

         // create file
        fout= new PrintWriter("EEGLogger.csv");
        String headerFile = "IED_COUNTER, IED_INTERPOLATED, IED_RAW_CQ, IED_AF3, IED_F7, IED_F3, IED_FC5, IED_T7, " +
                            "IED_P7, IED_O1, IED_O2, IED_P8, IED_T8, IED_FC6, IED_F4, IED_F8, IED_AF4, " + 
                            "IED_GYROX, IED_GYROY,IED_TIMESTAMP";
        // Writes the header to the file
        fout.println(headerFile);
        fout.println();
      ...
```

I do a `fout.close()` in a `finally` statement, but that still doesn't help get any output to the file. Any ideas here?

Comment: did you try with `print`, `write`, `append` ? did you flush and close the writer?

Comment: [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) hides any I/O errors: *Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions, although some of its constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking [`checkError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError--).*

Comment: @Andreas that's why I suggested to create a FileWriter and you did no like it. And still my best practice is to create File object too to get the absolute path, so the guy could check where the file really is

Comment: @gusto2 They (well, I) don't like you saying you 'have to' do that. You don't, but it's one solution.

Comment: @gusto A `FileWriter` has another purpose than a `PrintWriter`. Suggesting to use another class just because you get the exception is not a good idea. You can easily use the `PrintWriter` but you have to know how to deal with errors. That's it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose IMHO it improves resiliency (you will get the exception the same way as from all other IO operations). Not getting any message in case of exception and manually checking is more C approach. `have to know how to deal with errors` that's what mised the guy at the first..

Comment: @gusto2 This has nothing to do with resilience. As I told you, the _purpose_ of both classes is different! If you need (whatever that means) a `PrintWriter`, maybe because you use the special-purpose methods, then ... well ... then use it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  I agree with you, the purpose is different. IMHO the purpose of the PrintWriter is formatting and encoding (regardless of writing into the file, socket, pipe, ...). I consider using the PrintWriter directly for files as shortcut, where not throwing exceptions is counter-intuitive (as all other IO functionality throw IOException).  Please correct/explain if you don't agree. (I'd be curious if Vlad had really an exception or just file was written to different location)

Comment: @gusto2 `new FileWriter(fileName)` is just convenience for `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName))`. Since `new PrintWriter(fileName)` is convenience for `new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName))))`, the only thing you're accomplishing by doing `new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))` is dropping the `BufferedWriter`, causing potential performance degradation. You are in no way preventing exceptions from being suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. You are looking in the wrong place, i.e. not the current working directory, or
2. You don't have write access to the current working directory.

If you had used a `FileWriter` and not got an `IOException`, that would rule out (2).

I've seen about a million answers and comments here this week claiming that the current working directory equals the location of the JAR file, but it doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

You could open a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

```
fout = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("EEGLogger.csv"));
...
fout.flush();
fout.close()
```

I believe the PrintWriter is intended for formatting and character encoding. [api docs states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) `Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream` and as well `Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions`.

Using the FileWriter as parameter would force you to handle any IOException that may happen so if the file is not created or not writable, you will immediately get this information.

Another situation can happen if the file is created and you are just looking for the file at incorrect location.  I'd suggest to create a File object too, to see where the file really resides (what's your real working directory)

```
File f = new File("EEGLogger.csv");
fout = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f));
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: No you don't: [`PrintWriter(String fileName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.lang.String-)

Comment: you are right, I just cheked. So I'd assume the file is created, but in another place than you expect it.

Comment: You still need to say *why*. Merely suggesting alternatives isn't an answer.